# Merge lists in Lisp

Tags: recursion, lisp, common-lisp

I am trying to take a list representing a binary search tree and output a list elements in order so `(displayBST '(10(5(3(2()())())())()))` -> `(2 3 5 10)`. All I can seem to mange to get is  list looking like `(((2 3) 5) 10)` and I am not sure how to make all numbers base elements.

```
(let((SUMS))
(defun displayBST(elements)
 ;IF NO ELEMENTS return SUMS

 (cond((null elements)
           nil)
      ;if both branches null return first element
      ((and(null (second elements))(null (third elements)))
            (print (first elements))
            (first elements))
      ;if left branch not null
      ((not(null (second elements)))
            ;if right branch null
            (cond((null (third elements))
                      ;set SUMS to (left branch) and first element
                      (setf SUMS (list (displayBST(second elements)) (first elements))))
                   ;else set SUMS to (left branch) and first element and (right branch)
                  (t(SETF sums (append (displayBST(second elements))(first elements)(displayBST(third elements)))))))
      ;if left branch null and right not null
      ((not (null(third elements)))
           ;set SUMS to first element and (right branch)
           (setf SUMS (list (first elements) (displayBST(third elements))))))))
```

Comment: you can use `flatten` on the resulting list `(((2 3) 5) 10)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about how you join a given element to the value returned recursively by the function. If you want X + Y = (X Y) you should use (cons X (list Y)). Therefore the base case (i.e. (null (second elements)) and (null (third elements)) should return (list (first elements)).
What you want is something like this:

```
(let((SUMS))
(defun displayBST(elements)
 ;IF NO ELEMENTS return SUMS

 (cond((null elements)
           nil)
      ;if both branches null return first element
      ((and(null (second elements))(null (third elements)))
            (print (first elements))
            (list (first elements)))
      ;if left branch not null
      ((not(null (second elements)))
            ;if right branch null
            (cond((null (third elements))
                      ;set SUMS to (left branch) and first element
                      (setf SUMS (append (displayBST(second elements)) (list (first elements)))))
                   ;else set SUMS to (left branch) and first element and (right branch)
                  (t(SETF sums (append (displayBST(second elements))(first elements)(displayBST(third elements)))))))
      ;if left branch null and right not null
      ((not (null(third elements)))
           ;set SUMS to first element and (right branch)
           (setf SUMS (cons (first elements) (displayBST(third elements))))))))
```

Comment: Defining a (top-level) function inside a lexical closure is valid, but may have amusing (and by "amusing", I may mean "terrifying") consequences. It is probably better to wrap suitably-smaller parts of your implementation inside a lexical environment created by a `let` inside the function (by using `flet` or `labels` as appropriate).